# Why Augmented Dickey-Fuller results are different in R and Python

Tags: python, r, time-series

why the ADF test would have such a drastically different result in R vs Python?
Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rakannimer/air-passengers?resource=download

The R test suggests that the time series is stationary. The Python test - non-stationary.

**Python**

```
df = pd.read_csv("../data/air_passengers.csv")
adf_result = adfuller(df['Passengers'])

ADF Statistic: 0.8153688792060371
p-value: 0.9918802434376408
Number of Lags Used: 13
```

**R**:

```
air <- readr::read_csv("../data/air_passengers.csv")
adf.test(air$Passengers)

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

Dickey-Fuller = -7.318571346919138243, Lag order = 5,
p-value = 0.01000000000000000021
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

The time series is clearly non-stationary.
[image]

Comment: Which R package's `adf.test` are you using? It might have different defaults for lag order.

Comment: Thank you Jon. It was the lag order and the regression argument that needed to be adjusted for the results to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as often, is in the documentation.

For one, note that these functions default to a different number of lags; Python's `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller` has chosen 13 here whereas R's `tseries::adf.test` went with 5. You can directly change this in R using `k`, whereas in Python you have to set `maxlags` *and*  set `autolag = None` to stop the function from picking a different value.

Still, aligning the number of lags won't get you the same results. This is what R does:

> The general regression equation which incorporates a constant and a linear trend is used [..]

And this is Python's `regression` argument:

> `regression {“c”, ”ct”, ”ctt”, ”n”}`: Constant and trend order to include in regression.
>
> ```
>    “c” : constant only (default).
>    “ct” : constant and trend.
>    ...
> ```

These pieces of information should let you obtain the same results in both packages -- you have to fit the same number of lags and `tseries::adf.test` will only do constant & trend.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend that I use AIC/BIC methods for lag selection and never use the default settings?

Comment: @Roman I'm afraid I don't have much experience with time series modelling so cannot comment on that.